# How can I create my own Tor alternative?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, source-code

I'm not technically competent, but I was wondering how I could create my own Tor alternative using Visual Studio, Notepad++ or any other coding software and perhaps some links to the type of scripts I'd need to run in order to build a browser that connects to a network similar to Tor, Freenet/Frost, Zeronet, Lokinet, etc etc. I want to add my own custom .xxxxxx domains (like, say .example) instead of it being .onion or localhost. It's just a fun project I want to do that I might release once finished.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not technically competent

What you are talking about is totally possible but not an easy task for the newbie. However you can make your own Tor network if you're willing to put the effort into it. Tor is completely open-source.

From the Tor [FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#PrivateTorNetwork):

> **How do I set up my own private Tor network?**
>
> If you want to experiment locally with your own network, or you're cut
>   off from the Internet and want to be able to mess with Tor still, then
>   you may want to set up your own separate Tor network.
>
> To set up your own Tor network, you need to run your own authoritative
>   directory servers, and your clients and relays must be configured so
>   they know about your directory servers rather than the default public
>   ones.
>
> Apart from the somewhat tedious method of manually configuring a
>   couple of directory authorities, relays and clients there are two
>   separate tools that could help. One is Chutney, the other is Shadow.
>
> Chutney is a tool for configuring, controlling and running tests on a
>   testing Tor network. It requires that you have Tor and Python (2.5 or
>   later) installed on your system. You can use Chutney to create a
>   testing network by generating Tor configuration files (torrc) and
>   necessary keys (for the directory authorities). Then you can let
>   Chutney start your Tor authorities, relays and clients and wait for
>   the network to bootstrap. Finally, you can have Chutney run tests on
>   your network to see which things work and which do not. Chutney is
>   typically used for running a testing network with about 10 instances
>   of Tor. Every instance of Tor binds to one or two ports on localhost
>   (127.0.0.1) and all Tor communication is done over the loopback
>   interface. The Chutney README is a good starting point for getting it
>   up and running.
>
> Shadow is a network simulator that can run Tor through its Scallion
>   plug-in. Although it's typically used for running load and performance
>   tests on substantially larger Tor test networks than what's feasible
>   with Chutney, it also makes for an excellent debugging tool since you
>   can run completely deterministic experiments. A large Shadow network
>   is on the size of thousands of instances of Tor, and you can run
>   experiments out of the box using one of Shadow's several included
>   scallion experiment configurations. Shadow can be run on any linux
>   machine without root, and can also run on EC2 using a pre-configured
>   image. Also, Shadow controls the time of the simulation with the
>   effect that time-consuming tests can be done more efficiently than in
>   an ordinary testing network. The Shadow wiki and Shadow website are
>   good places to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you have to be very experienced in network anonymity and math, technical background will come to you while you will be implementing it, but first of all you need a paper and a pencil to create a design of *each and every* moment of your network, only completing this task you're starting to write a first line of code

Answer (score 0):

I want tor for socially interact with people
And i also want a job